# TestNG & Selenium: Perform CRUD operations on entities with depedencies

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, testng

I am new to Selenium and TestNG I am not able to execute scripts in order.
I have to perform CRUD operation on entities as *Group*,*User*,*Location*,*Device*,*Profile*,*Role* which have dependicies in between them.

I have create a separate group for each operation (usin annotation) that I perform on each entity, as *addGroup*,*editGroup*,*deleteGroup* and so on for each entity above.
Some of entities is dependent on other as

**ADD GROUP**

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups={"loginGroup"},groups="addGroup")
 public void AddGroup() {}
```

***EDIT GROUP***

editGroup is dependent on addGroup operation as follows

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "loginGroup","addGroup"}, groups = "editGroup")
 public void editGroup() {}
```

***DELETE GROUP***

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups={"loginGroup","addGroup","deleteLocation"},groups="deleteGroup")
 public void deleteGroup() {}
```

***ADD LOCATION***

AddLocation operation is dependent on AddGroup.

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = {"loginGroup", "addGroup" }, groups = "addLocation")
 public void addLocation() {}
```

***EDIT LOCATION***

editLocation is dependent on AddLocation

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "loginGroup","addLocation"}, groups = "editLocation")
 public void editLocation() {}
```

***DELETE LOCATION***

deleteLocation is dependent on addLocation operation

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups={"loginGroup","addLocation"},groups="deleteLocation")
 public void deleteLocation(String locationId) {}
```

***ADD ROLE***

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "loginGroup"}, groups = "addRole",dataProviderClass=AddNewRoleDataProvider.class)
 public void addRole() { }
```

***EDIT ROLE***

editRole is dependent on addRole

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "loginGroup","addRole"}, groups = "editRole")
 public void editRole() {}
```

***DELETE ROLE***

deleteRole is dependent on addLocation operation

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "loginGroup", "addRole", "deleteUser" }, groups = "deleteRole")
 public void deleteRole() { }
```

***ADD USER***

AddUser operation has dependency on AddLocation,AddGroup,AddRole Operations.

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = {"loginGroup", "addGroup", "addLocation","addRole"}, groups = "addUser")
 public void AddUser() { }
```

***EDIT USER***

editUser operation is dependent on addUser operation

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "loginGroup","addUser"}, groups = "editUser")
 public void editUser() { }
```

***DELETE USER***

delete user operation is dependent on addUser Operation

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = { "loginGroup","addUser"}, groups = "deleteUser")
 public void deleteUser(String userId) throws Exception {}
```

now I want to run this operations as suite following is the code to run this scripts as suite

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups={"addGroup","addLocation","addRole","addUser",
   "editGroup","editLocation","editRole","editUser",
   "deleteUser","deleteLocation","deleteRole","deleteGroup"})
 public void startSuite() {}
```

when I run my suite it will delete Location before adding User thus addUser operation gets terminated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are kinda overcomplicating this scenario, wouldn't be easier to have tests for each entity separately in the class?Like

```
@Test(dependsOnGroups = {"loginGroup", "groupCrud", "locationCrud","roleCrud"}, 
       groups = "userCrud")
public TestUserCrudOperations {

    @Test(priority = 0)
    public void addUser() {}

    @Test(priority = 1) 
    public void editUser() {}

    @Test(priority = 2)
    public void deteleUser() {}

   //method with lower priority is executed first

}
```

You will gain much more readable and maintainable code by separation of tests into classes like this (and you will aso avoid having too much groups with difficult dependencies).

Comment: thanks for quick reply but my addUser() is dependent on addGroup(),addLocation(),addRole() how can I mention that ?

Comment: See my edit, just add the `@Test` annotation on the each class, this way you will avoid specifying test group onto each test.

Comment: But still, remember that tests should be as independent as possible so for instance `loginGroup` could be refactored into some `@BeforeSuite` method (but this depends on your scenario of course).

Comment: I got the point but when I mention locationCrud in dependsOnGroups then it will Perform Add,Update and Delete on Location but I don't want to perform delete before addUser() so how can I Handel this scenario.

Comment: I have updated code as per suggested approach but It while executing  userCrud test it is executing groupCrud operations, but it is deleting the group after creating it which I am using further while create user I thing I am missing out something ?

Comment: Getting folowing erro using following approach `org.testng.TestNGException: 
DependencyMap::Method "TestGroupCrudOperations.AddGroup(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)[pri:0, instance:com.onemobility.scripts.group.TestGroupCrudOperations@d16dc8]" depends on nonexistent group "loginGroup"`